# Launch another App and wait till it loaded

Tags: android

I need to launch 3-part App if it is not running and wait for it to complete loading to start interacting with it.
How to start app is clear, but how to determine when it loaded without any additional timers or loops codes?

---

interact in concrete situation means send some data over TCP connection to same localhost. But firstly i must launch taht listening app main activity and then send data over socket.

(for example, well known MapFactor navigation app accepts remoute commands over TCPIP only. From my app i need to send GPS destionation to calculate route for navigation, but if MapFactor is not running it is not listening to tcp socket).

Comment: What does "complete loading" mean? What does "start interacting with it" mean?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're asking for, but sounds sort of like something you could do with broadcast receivers and an intent action. Before launching the other app, register a receiver that listens for your action. When the other app is ready, it can send an intent with that action.